# magento2 : retrieve images path of a product programmatically?

Tags: magento2, product-images, delete

I'm using this code to retrieve all products "out of stock" and export them in a csv so I can use the "import" tab (behavior delete) to clean old products.

```
$productCollection = $obj->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
$collection = $productCollection
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            //->setPageSize(700) //Selecting 500 products pour TEST plus rapide
            ->load();
echo "sku" . ';' . "name" . ';' . "mgs_brand" . ';' . "urbmag_season" . "\n";
foreach($collection as $product){

    $productType = $product->getTypeId(); // regarde si CONFIGURABLE

    if ($productType == "configurable" AND !$product->isAvailable()) { // CONF + OUT OF STOCK
    $productSku = $product->getSku();
    $productName = $product->getName();
    $productBrand = $product->getAttributeText('mgs_brand');
    $productSeason = $product->getAttributeText('urbmag_season');
        echo $productSku.';'.$productName.';'.$productBrand.';'.$productSeason."\n";

        $children = $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($product); // simple associés
        foreach ($children as $child) {
      $childSku = $child->getSku();
      $childName = $child->getName();
            echo $childSku.';'.$childName.';'.$productBrand.';'.$productSeason."\n";
        }
    }
}
```

I like to add a column with the media path so I can delete images associated to the product. I'm looking for the command like `$productImages = $product->getXXXXXXXXXXX();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

$productImages = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')->init($product, 'product_page_image_large')->getUrl();